# Yup validation in React always prompts "Please select an option" even when an option is selected

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, yup, react-typescript

I am using a custom form library in a React project along with yup for field validation. In my PensionAmountField component, I have a radio group where users can select a pension amount option. Even when an option is selected, the yup validation erroneously prompts the "Please select an option" error message. I need help identifying why this error persists despite a selection being made.

Here is the relevant code:

Parent Component:

```
    const formality = useFormality();
    const handlePensionAmount = (value: string, fieldName: string) => {
    setPensionAmount(value);
    formality.updateField(fieldName, value);
    if (value === "Nominate") {
      setIsNominateAmountChoiceSelected(true);
    } else {
      setIsNominateAmountChoiceSelected(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Title text="Update the amount you would like to receive" />
      <PensionAmountField
        isTTR={isTTR}
        isTAP={isTAP}
        midFinancialYearStart={midFinancialYearStart}
        pensionDetails={pensionDetails}
        onChange={handlePensionAmount}
        formality={formality}
      />
```

Child component:

```
import { useFormality, Field } from "formality-library";
import { Label, RadioGroup } from "generic-ui-library"; 
import { Inform } from "icons-library";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { themed } from "theme-provider-library";

const PensionAmountField = ({
  isTTR,
  isTAP,
  midFinancialYearStart,
  pensionDetails,
  onChange,
  formality,
}) => {
  const FIELD_NAME = "pension-amount-radio";
  const value = formality.value(FIELD_NAME);

  useEffect(() => {
    formality.initField(FIELD_NAME, "", true);
  }, []);

  const pensionAmountOptions = [
    {
      value: "Minimum",
      label: `Select the minimum amount (${pensionDetails.minimum})`,
    },
    ...(isTAP
      ? [
          {
            value: "Fixed",
            label: `Select the fixed amount (${pensionDetails.fixed})`,
          },
        ]
      : []),
    ...(isTTR || isTAP
      ? [
          {
            value: "Maximum",
            label: `Select the maximum amount (${pensionDetails.maximum})`,
          },
        ]
      : []),
    ...(midFinancialYearStart && isTTR
      ? [
          {
            value: "Pro rate maximum",
            label: `Select the pro-rata maximum amount (${pensionDetails.proRataMaximum})`,
          },
        ]
      : []),
    {
      value: "Nominate",
      label: "Nominate an amount of your choice",
    },
  ];

  const validPensionAmountValues = pensionAmountOptions.map(
    (option) => option.value
  );

  const pensionAmountSchema = yup.object().shape({
    pensionAmountRadio: yup
      .string()
      .required("Please select an option.")
      .oneOf(validPensionAmountValues, "Selected option is invalid."),
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Field fieldName={FIELD_NAME} validationRules={pensionAmountSchema}>
        <RadioGroup
          options={pensionAmountOptions}
          field={{
            name: "pension-amount-radio",
            value: value,
            onChange: (e) => onChange(e.target.value, FIELD_NAME),
          }}
        />
      </Field>
    </>
  );
};

export default themed(PensionAmountField);
```

Things to note:

The FIELD_NAME constant is set as "pension-amount-radio".
The yup schema is expecting a value that is one of the validPensionAmountValues.
The RadioGroup component is being fed the proper options and also gets its value from formality.value(FIELD_NAME).
Any insights or suggestions on why yup is not recognizing the selected option would be appreciated!